# IndexOutOfBoundsExpection when testing asynchronous functions in Kotlin with mockk

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, junit, kotlin-coroutines, mockk

When testing a function I have problems with an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Normally, `usersInRangeViewStates` should have size two, with the first entry `Resource.Loading` and the second `Resource.Success`. Because `usersInRange(...)` is an asynchronous function and I have to wait for it, I added `runTest{ ... }` and `advanceUntilIdle()`. I actually thought that the test with the `Asserts` then waits until the asynchronous function is finished, but that only happens sometimes. Does anyone see the error or can you suggest me a better solution?

Code:

```
val usersInRange: MutableLiveData<Resource<GETUsers>> = MutableLiveData()

fun getUsersInRange(myUserGeoPoint: GeoPoint, searchRadiusInMeter: Int) = viewModelScope.launch {
  usersInRange.postValue(Resource.Loading())
  val response = usersInRange(myUserGeoPoint, searchRadiusInMeter)
  usersInRange.postValue(Resource.Success(response))
}

private suspend fun usersInRange(myUserGeoPoint: GeoPoint, searchRadiusInMeter: Int)
= withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val usersInRangeBuffer = GETUsers()
    if(users.value is Resource.Success) {
        for(user in (users.value as Resource.Success<GETUsers>).data.users) {
            if(user.value.id == myUserID) continue
            if(user.value.isInRange(myUserGeoPoint, searchRadiusInMeter)) {
                usersInRangeBuffer.users[user.key] = user.value
            }
        }
    }
    usersInRangeBuffer
}
```

Test:

```
private lateinit var usersInRangeViewStates: MutableList<Resource<GETUsers>>

@Before
fun setUp() {
  usersInRangeViewStates = mutableListOf()
  
  viewModel.usersInRange.observeForever {
    usersInRangeViewStates.add(it)
  }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
@Test
fun `getUsersInRange() called should return 0 Users from 2 tested Users (plus myUser)`() = runTest {
    val myUserGeoPoint = GeoPoint(1.0, 1.0)
    val searchRadiusInMeter = 1000

    val user01ID = "exampleUser01ID"
    val user02ID = "exampleUser02ID"
    val user01Location = GETLocation(0.0, 0.0)
    val user02Location = GETLocation(0.0, 0.0)
    val myUser = GETUser()
    val user01 = GETUser(location = user01Location)
    val user02 = GETUser(location = user02Location)
    val mapUsers = mutableMapOf(myUserID to myUser, user01ID to user01, user02ID to user02)
    val users = GETUsers(mapUsers)
    val getUsers = Resource.Success(users)

    viewModel.users.value = getUsers
    viewModel.getUsersInRange(myUserGeoPoint, searchRadiusInMeter)
    advanceUntilIdle()

    Assert.assertTrue(usersInRangeViewStates[0] is Resource.Loading)
    Assert.assertEquals(0, (usersInRangeViewStates[1] as Resource.Success).data.users.size)
    Assert.assertFalse((usersInRangeViewStates[1] as Resource.Success).data.users.containsKey(user01ID))
    Assert.assertFalse((usersInRangeViewStates[1] as Resource.Success).data.users.containsKey(user02ID))
    Assert.assertFalse((usersInRangeViewStates[1] as Resource.Success).data.users.containsKey(myUserID))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewModel.getUsersInRange` sends `Resource.Success(response)` to the `MutableLiveData`, which then asks the main thread to run `usersInRangeViewStates.add(it)`.

`advanceUntilIdle` will wait for "run observer" task to be scheduled. But because the observing is done outside of coroutines, it probably will not wait for the task to actually finish running.

I think you can do your testing as another thing to run on the main thread.

```kotlin
withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
    Assert.assertTrue(usersInRangeViewStates[0] is Resource.Loading)
    Assert.assertEquals(0, (usersInRangeViewStates[1] as Resource.Success).data.users.size)
    Assert.assertFalse((usersInRangeViewStates[1] as Resource.Success).data.users.containsKey(user01ID))
    Assert.assertFalse((usersInRangeViewStates[1] as Resource.Success).data.users.containsKey(user02ID))
    Assert.assertFalse((usersInRangeViewStates[1] as Resource.Success).data.users.containsKey(myUserID))
}
```

Comment: I changed `Dispatchers.Main` to `Dispatchers.IO` and it worked.

Comment: If `IO` works but not `Main`, that contradicts my theory. And I feel weird getting reputation points for that.